# Create an ActionLink for a DisplayFor value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, html.actionlink, displayfor

I have coded a C# MVC 5 Internet Application and have a question about an `ActionLink` in a `View`.

I have the following code:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mapLocations.Count)
</td>
```

Is it possible to create an `ActionLink` for this above displayed value?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have tried the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.mapLocations.Count, "Index", "MapLocation", new { mapCompanyid = item.Id }, null)
```

I am getting a compilation error as follows:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1928: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<CanFindLocation.ViewModels.MapCompaniesViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string, object, object)' has some invalid arguments
```

**EDIT2**

Do I need the DisplayFor code to display the value in the ActionLink?

Maybe something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mapLocations.Count), "Index", "MapLocation", new { mapCompanyid = item.Id }, null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work :-

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.mapLocations.Count, "// action name //", "// controller name //", new{ mapCompanyid = item.Id  }, new{ // html attributes // })
```

Just match your Actionlink it's structure should look like below :-

```
Html.ActionLink(item.mapLocations.Count, //  <--Title
            "Index",   // <-- ActionMethod
            "MapLocation",  // <-- Controller Name.
            new { mapCompanyid = item.Id }, // <-- Route arguments.
            null  // <-- htmlArguments.
            )
```

Comment: The item.mapLocations.Count is in a loop, and as such, will not work.

Comment: do you want item.mapLocations.Count in title or route parameters in actionlink???

Comment: I am wanting to display the Count value as the text for an Action link. Can you have a look at my edit?

Comment: I have coded that, yet the error in my post occurs.

Comment: this is not possible...just try @item.mapLocations.Count instead of item.mapLocations.Count

Comment: The @ also did not work. I have not specifically coded any custom helpers.

Comment: Do I need any code as follows: modelItem => item.mapLocations.Count?

Comment: I am actually using custom helpers (I was not aware of what they were).